# How to add localization in App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, app-store-connect

According to the fact that `iTunes Connect` was changed not long time ago to App Store Connect, I can't find how to add localization language in `App Store Connect`, right now I see only English language there, how to add other languages there? I want to localize app description for different countries. 
[image]

Comment: You probably can't once you publish it.

Comment: @ElTomato oh, would it be possible to add any other language when I will be adding new version of the app?

Comment: It's not possible to add localization for build that are already in "Ready for Sale". You need to create a new version for you to be able to add localization.

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing really changed between App Store Connect and iTunes Connect when it comes do adding and removing languages/localizations.

Your app needs to be in an **editable state** for you to be able to do this:

> **Language**: The language you choose to localize your metadata. This property is editable depending on the app status.

If you cannot add/delete languages, simply create a new version of the app. The changes will only be active on the store, once the new version is approved by Apple and live.

Source: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devf29afbb74